# IF statement inside a LINQ SELECT

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to produce an IF conditional statement inside of a "select new" that checks the values of two fields in order to fill a property.

```
from e in Employees
where e.EmployeeID == id
select new {
    EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
    Status = (if e.col1.HasValue then "This Value" else if e.col2.HasValue then "Other Value")
}
```

The columns are nullable and therefore the column types are DateTime? data types.

Only one or the other column will have a datetime value, not both.

How do I go about doing this???

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
Status = e.col1.HasValue ? "This Value" : (e.col2.HasValue ? "Other Value" : null)
```

Comment: You beautiful man, I was getting a NullReferenceException on Windows Phone when returning Contact.Companies ... trying to get Contact.Companies.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName in a LINQ query was bombing out ... the following worked great!

CompanyName = (c.Companies.Count() > 0) ? c.Companies.FirstOrDefault().CompanyName : ""

Answer (score 3):

use the null coelacing operator for this

```
Status = e.col1.HasValue ? e.col1.Value ?? "This Value" : e.col2.Value ?? "Other Value"
```

Comment: Actually it does the reverse of what the OP specifies.