# Statement for Query

Tags: c#, var

I am really new to Linq statements but let me say I am loving them.  Any here here is my issue

```
var faults = from e in _context.Faults
                     where e.Car_FK == Car_ID && e.Model_FK == Model_ID
                     select new { e.Time, e.Drive_Type};
```

I was wondering if it is possible to have an if statement in there, so that if Model_ID doesn't exist I can set another value like

```
      ViewData["Message"] =  "Please make another selection"
```

I am passing in Car_ID and Model_ID

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030041/if-statement-inside-a-linq-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030041/if-statement-inside-a-linq-select)

Comment: just to add, var is implicitly typed variable, which holds the type assigned to it at compile time, these statements are LINQ query expressions

Comment: To cleart it up: What goes into ViewData normally? With what tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having made your query, you can test the availability of items with the `Any` LINQ extension method

```
if (faults.Any()) {
    // Display faults
} else {
    ViewData["Message"] =  "Please make another selection"  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `? :` operator to have an if statement inside your query or if you need to filter an item based on the condition, you can put it in the `where` clause.

However in your case you probably want to put this outside the query, because you want to change the logic of the application:

```
 if(Model_ID==null)
    ViewData["Message"] =  "Please make another selection"   
 else
 {
    var faults = from e in _context.Faults  
                 where e.Car_FK == Car_ID && e.Model_FK == Model_ID  
                 select new { e.Time, e.Drive_Type};  
    //...
 }
```

**Edit:** See comments

Comment: Although correct this isn't helpful. Maybe you should explain what it is or provide a link to an example

Comment: Sorry, I responded too fast. I fixed my answer, please conside your downvote.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko it's not even correct: the OP seems to want different behavior based on a condition, not simply a different value based on a condition.  You can't do that with the conditional operator.

Comment: I was thinking he wanted to select another value in case the Model_ID is null, only later I realized that the message is independent from the query. So sorry again, see my correction I think it's a good response to the OPs question.